# I don't understand why my formset is not valid

Tags: django

I am trying to make a registration panel in my project. When I check if the form is valid I get `False` as a result and don't understand why.

Here is some of my code:

**views.py**:

```
@unauthorized_user
def registerPage(request):
    form=createUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = createUserForm(request.POST)
        print (form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            group = Group.objects.get(name='user')
            user.groups.add(group)
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            Customer.objects.create(user=user, name=username, email=email)
            messages.success(request, 'Account created for ' + username)
            print(group.user_set.all())

            return redirect('login.html')
    context={'form':form}

    return render(request,'register.html',context)
```

**Template**:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="Username-label">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
        </div>

        <div class="Password-label">
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"required>
        </div>

        <div class="Email-label">
            <label><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

**models.py**:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Even if you render the form manually one needs to set the `name` attribute correctly for their input tags. Let's forget correctly you don't even set the `name` attribute.

Comment: I am newbie in django and don't understand how it works correctly, can you be more precisely please ?

Comment: Please post your creatUserForm class - unless you are trying to use the django built-in which is UserCreationForm and misspelled it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `createUserForm()` class (which is where the validation is being performed) I can only guess what your issue might be - you also appear to be using a Login template to register users which won't work.

Regardless, I would suggest using as much of the built-in Django account management system as possible instead of trying to roll your own since you are new to this. A great explanation and code examples can be [found here](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-signup-tutorial).

If you want to extend the built-in Django `UserCreationForm()` class to add custom fields you want to collect, you can do something like this in your `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from myapp.models import Customer


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save()
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        user_profile.save()
        group = Group.objects.get(name='user')
        user.groups.add(group)
        Customer.objects.create(user=user, name=user.username, email=user_profile.email)
        return user, user_profile
```

Then your view might be something like this:

```
@unauthorized_user
def registerPage(request):
    form=UserCreateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user, user_profile = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account created for ' + user.username)
            return redirect(reverse('login'))
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'register.html',context)
```

Also, your HTML is wrong for the view. It should be something like:

```
 {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="Username-label">
                <label><b>Username</b></label>
                <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
            </div>
    
            <div class="Password-label">
                <label><b>Password</b></label>
                <input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="Password-label">
                <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
                <input name="password2" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password confirmation" required>
            </div>
    
            <div class="Email-label">
                <label><b>Email</b></label>
                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    
        </div>
    </form>
```